# Magento2 error ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: magento2, migration

I moved my **Magento 2.2.5** based website into another existing site in-order to make them both a multi-site website. I used a paid migration tool and all seemed to go fine, now when I am editing some products to add them to a category for one of my store views I am getting the below error. I even tried deleting the category from the admin panel and then tried for re-creating the category thinking, maybe something with the category just didn't migrate over correctly.

> No such entity with id = 128

```
 Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 102
```

I am not sure how to find out what entity id 128 is . I checked all my other categories which have category images and descriptions added to them all that looks fine.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further and or how to fix it? I also checked my folder and file permissions already

Comment: reindexing after migration?

Comment: ya i reindexed, i even compiled and re-deployed

Comment: var/cache/*
var/page_cache/*
var/view_preprocessed/*
var/generation/*

Comment: @Jayreis any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

This issue is showing after the data migration because some
product or category have duplicate rewrite Url in `url_rewrite` table

a) You can search the duplicate url and rename/ remove

b) `vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage/DbStorage.php`

Edit  this file or overwrite this file

```
            protected function insertMultiple($data)
                {
                    try {
                        return true;
```

Note : after changes run the reindex command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old now but I've been having this issue on a 2.2.11 install when trying to save the category in my local after copying down the DB from production. This error was caused by DEFINER being set in my sql file then importing that into my local DB which caused silent permission issues. No errors were thrown except for this one with seemingly no reason.

If you run into this issue after importing the DB. Open the SQL file you imported and check for the "DEFINER" line (ex. DEFINER=`app`@`%`) and remove it. There's other articles here on stackoverflow to guide you on different methods you can use to remove definers from your sql file.